# How to get the fields that match the request?

Tags: java, lucene, solr

I need your help to get more information in my solR query's response.

i've got a simple input text which allows me to query several fields in the same query.

So my query  looks like this
"q=email:martyn+OR+name:martynn+OR+commercial:martyn ..."

Is it possible in the response to know the fields where "martynn" has been found?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your query string:

```
hl=true&hl.fl=*
```

which tells solr to highlight the fields where the matches were made.

This [solr wiki page](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/HighlightingParameters) describes all the highlighting parameters available with solr.